# Naming conventions for newtype deconstructors (destructors?)

Tags: coding-standards, haskell

Looking into Haskell's standard library we can see:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }

newtype WrappedMonad m a = WrapMonad { unwrapMonad :: m a }

newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }
```

Apparently, there (at least) 3 different prefixes used to unwrap a value inside a `newtype`: *un-*, *run-* and *get-*. (Moreover *run-* and *get-* capitalizes the next letter while *un-* doesn't.) This seems confusing.

- Are there any reasons for that, or is that just a historical thing?
- If I design my own `newtype`, what prefix should I use and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convention regarding capitalization is that the first letter of each word is capitalized. So the "w" in "unwrap" is lower-case because "unwrap" is one word, i.e. it's "unwrap [the] monad", not "un wrap [the] monad".

The reason that `runStateT` is named `runStateT` is that this best describes how the function is used - it's used to execute/run a state transformer. It wouldn't make sense to call the other deconstructors in your example `runSomething` because they're not used to run or execute anything.

The distinction between `get` and `unwrap` seems a bit more arbitrary (at least for records with only one member), but in this case I think the word `unwrap` was simply chosen because it fits nicely with the name `WrappedMonad`.

In the end I'd say that it's not necessary to pick a name that unmistakably marks a function as being a destructor because that's not really relevant. So the "convention" for naming deconstructors is simply to pick one that best describes what it does and how it's supposed to be used.